# Will it be possible to limit Comos DB trigger for insert operation?

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm having a condition where I'm supposed to update the status inside Cosmos DB, but I do have a trigger for Cosmos DB container. That means, if I update/insert the status, trigger will be fired (because container will change) and it will cause the infinite loop. Any possible ways to solve this problem please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the Cosmos DB Trigger for Azure Functions, no, currently there is no way to distinguish the event between an insert and an update.

It might be possible if you have a CreatedTime property that you can check to see if it matches the document Timestamp (_ts property) but nothing that can say the originating operation for the event.

Comment: You are right. I added status flag and checked it to distinguish the operations. It's working fine. Thanks

Comment: Please remember to mark the answers to others can benefit.

Comment: Completed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you mean pre-triggers or post-triggers in cosmos db,it won't cause the infinite loop.Because they need to invoke with code,like this:

`RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions(); requestOptions.setPostTriggerInclude(Arrays.asList("trgPostUpdateMetadata")); asyncClient.createDocument(containerLink, item, requestOptions, false).toBlocking();`

If you update/insert the job status without `requestOptions.setPostTriggerInclude(Arrays.asList("trgPostUpdateMetadata"));`,the trigger won't be invoked.

If you mean azure cosmos db in Azure Function,just disabled it then update/insert job status.